# Socket.IO disconnect unwanted users

Tags: mongodb, sockets, security, access-control

I use this code : (Server side)

```
io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, accept) {
  var domain = handshakeData.headers.referer.replace('http://','').replace('https://','').split(/[/?#]/)[0];
  if('myDomain.com'==domain)
    accept(null, true);
  else 
    return accept('Deny', false);
});
```

But unwanted domain/user all time can use my server function and have access to my MongoDB (thought server).

Can somebody help me how to secure my server?

Or how to close only connection with unwanted user?

Comment: https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/15/auth-with-socket-io/

Comment: I was looking for it , and try set it up but i got all time errors . Can somebody help with it ? I can pay by paypal

Comment: Or any idea how i can disconnect user if somebody get deny by it code                     return accept('Deny', false);